# The input does not contain any JSON tokens

Tags: c#, json

```
  public void AddNewCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    
      var path = Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
     
      string title = Title;

      string presPath = $"{path}/presets/{title}";



      toSave save = new toSave
      {
          size_1 = s_ize,
          angle_1 = a_ngle,
          auto_1 = automatic
      };
     

      DirectoryInfo inf = new DirectoryInfo(presPath);
    
     
          for (int i = -1; i < inf.GetFiles().Length; i++)
          {
          Console.WriteLine(i);
              if (!System.IO.File.Exists($"{presPath}/{i+1}.command"))
              {

                  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter($"{presPath}/{i+1}.command"))
                  {
                  string str =    JsonSerializer.Serialize(save, typeof(toSave)); 

                  sw.Write(str);
                      ReadCommand();
                      HideCommandTask();
                  }
              }
          }
  }
```

Сериализация проходит в этом методе, здесь ошибок нету

```
public void ReadCommand()
 {
     CommandList = new List<Commands>();

   
     var path = Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;

     string title = Title;

     string presPath = $"{path}/presets/{title}";

 

     DirectoryInfo inf = new DirectoryInfo(presPath);
     for (int i = 0; i < inf.GetFiles().Length; i++)
     {

         string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"{presPath}/{i}.command");


         Console.WriteLine(str);              
         JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
         {
             PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            
         };
          
      toSave saver = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<toSave>(str, options); // Здесь выдаёт ошибку "System.Text.Json.JsonException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |"
```

А вот в методе десеарелизации выдаёт ошибку
Прошу помочь мне решить данную проблему.

Comment: Типичная проблема десериализации пусто строки. Вы же сделали  Console.WriteLine(str); - вот и смотрите что там.

Comment: Там он выдаёт json файл красивый и заполненный.

Comment: Программы не врут, если вам пишет "Входная строка не содержит JSON", значит там нет JSON, либо он битый. Точку остановки ставьте и смотрите что в `str`, заодно и сюда, в вопрос закиньте, чтоб мы тоже знали.

Comment: В логи бесконечно начинает идти текст файла, а вот само его содержание:
"{"size_1":666.900024,"angle_1":999.900024,"auto_1":true}"

Comment: Еще раз повторю, программы не врут. Делайте значит [минимальный, самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который мы сможем скопировать и запустить, воспроизведя тем самым проблему у себя. Пока [не воспроизводится](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l05QJg) и вопрос можно смело закрывать по этой причине.

Comment: Показанный в комментарии json прекрасно десериадизуется. Попробуйте вывести str.Length, быть может пустую строку не видно, а ноль увидите.

Answer (score 0):

Решение скрывалось в проверке десереализуемой строки на содержание `null` значения или пустого текста: `""`.

```
if (str != "" & str != null)
{
var saver = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<toSave>(str, options);


CommandList.Add(new Commands { size = saver.size_1, angle = saver.angle_1, isAuto = saver.auto_1, number = i });

Comm_List.ItemsSource = null;

Comm_List.ItemsSource = CommandList;

}`
```

Проверка помогла исправить ошибку, тем, что начала отсеивать json-строки и пустые друг от друга.

Comment: [String.IsNullOrEmpty(String) Метод](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty). И на будущее, отладкой научитесь пользоваться, ибо только вы знаете что у вас в коде твориться, и когда вам говорят "Там пустота", значит там пустота...